# Nim Game, Public Void Play and Calling Methods

Tags: java

Hello I am a student struggling to create a game of Nim for a homework assignment. I am currently confused on the in the first file public void play() method where in the comments, my teacher posted,

```
call computer;s play method, send it marbleCount, and
// reduce marblecount by the amount the computer takes
// Then you need to check for a winner
// switch the turn
```

I basically don't get how you would call the Computer play method, send it marbleCount or check for the winner. Can someone please give me some hints/help? I am extremely tired and have been working on this for a long time so if I missed something easy sorry. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * Represents a game of Nim, where players take turns removing marbles from a pile.
 * The player that takes the last marble wins the game.
 */
public class Nim
{
    public static int COMPUTER = 0;
    public static int HUMAN = 1;

    private Player computer;
    private Player human;
    private int marbleCount;
    private int turn;           // whose turn it is
    private int winner;

    /**
     * Constructs a Nim game.  There are two players, one is the computer and the other is human.
     * The player who gets to go first is chosen at random.  The number of marbles in the pile is
     * generated randomly between 10 and 100.  A message is displayed showing how many marbles the
     * starts with.  The contructor calls the play() method to start the game.
     */
    public Nim()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        // assign values for all instance fields before play() is called
        computer = new Player(COMPUTER);
        human = new Player (HUMAN);
        marbleCount = rand.nextInt(91) + 10;
        turn = rand.nextInt(2);
        winner = HUMAN;
        // JOptionPane - Show number of marbles
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(marbleCount);

        play();
    }

    /**
     * The play method continues game play until the pile is reduced to 0.  Whoever takes the last marble
     * loses the game.  At the beginning of each play, the number of marbles left is displayed.  The player
     * whose turn it is calls the Player play method, sending it the number of marbles left.  When the player
     * takes marbles, the marbleCount is decreased.  When the marbles are gone, the winner of the game is
     * displayed.
     */
    public void play()
    // while there are marbles left
    // if else for turn
    // if its the computers turn you are going to call the computer's play method,
    // last method in the player file
        // call computer;s play method, send it marbleCount, and
        // reduce marblecount by the amount the computer takes
        // Then you need to check for a winner
        // switch the turn
    // else human's turn
        //call the human's play method - send it marbleCount
            // reduce marbleCount by the human's take
            // check for a winner
            // switch the turn
    {
        while(marbleCount >= 0)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"There are " + marbleCount + "marbles left");
            if(turn = 0)

                turn = 1;
            else
                turn = 0;













        // At the end of play (when the loop exits), the winner is displayed
        if (winner == COMPUTER)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Computer wins!");
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Human wins!");
    }
}
```

end of the first file

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 * Represents a player in the game of Nim.  The player is either human or computer.
 * Humans are prompted for their plays.
 */
public class Player
{
    public static int COMPUTER = 0;
    public static int HUMAN = 1;

    private int type; // computer or human

    /**
     * Constructs a player of type t.  0 is COMPUTER, 1 is HUMAN.
     * If t is not 0 or 1, type will be set to HUMAN.
     * @param t type of player
     */
    public Player(int t)
    {
        type = t;
        if(!(type == 0 || type == 1))
            type = 1;
    }

    /**
     * Determines how many marbles are taken, and returns that number.
     * Human player will be asked how many marbles they want to take.
     * If the move is illegal, they will be asked again until they select a legal move.
     * The computer will take a random number of marbles between 1 and pileSize/2.
     * @param pileSize the number of marbles in the pile
     * @return the number of marbles taken by the player
     */
    public int play(int pileSize)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int numTaken;
        if(type == COMPUTER)
        {
            if(pileSize == 1)
            {
                numTaken = 1;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Computer took 1 marble ");
            }
            else
            {

            numTaken = r.nextInt(pileSize / 2) + 1;  // POSSIBLE ERROR
            pileSize = pileSize - numTaken;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Computer took " + numTaken + "marbles ");
            }
        }
        else
            {
                boolean correct;
                do
                {
                String numTakenbyhuman = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("There are " + pileSize + "marbles" + "How many marbles will you take ?");
                numTaken = Integer.parseInt(numTakenbyhuman);
                pileSize = pileSize - numTaken;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Computer took " + pileSize + " marbles ");
                if(1 <= numTaken <= pileSize / 2)
                    correct = false;
                else
                    correct = true;
                }
                while(!correct);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must take between " + pilesize/2 + " 1 marbles");


                }
                return numTaken;




            }




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it just means that, inside your `while` loop for `Nim.play()`, you need to alternate calls to the human player and the computer player. You already have an `if` to determine which player's turn it is. Just call `computer.play()` in the if when you update the turn, and `human.play()` when you take the other branch.

Answer (score 0):

In your Nim class you have a check where you toggle between turn, at the same place depending on the turn you have to call either Computer or Human, then the play method returns 'number of marbles taken' either by computer or Human, subtract this returned value from the marbleCount.

This will go on till marbleCount > 0 after which depending on the turn you decide on the winner.

I modified your code a bit, you can compare to see the difference

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
  * Represents a game of Nim, where players take turns removing marbles from a
  * pile. The player that takes the last marble wins the game.
  */
  public class Nim {
public static int   COMPUTER    = 0;

public static int   HUMAN       = 1;

private Player      computer;

private Player      human;

private int         marbleCount;

private int         turn;               // whose turn it is

private int         winner;

/**
 * Constructs a Nim game. There are two players, one is the computer and the
 * other is human. The player who gets to go first is chosen at random. The
 * number of marbles in the pile is generated randomly between 10 and 100. A
 * message is displayed showing how many marbles the starts with. The
 * contructor calls the play() method to start the game.
 */
public Nim() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    // assign values for all instance fields before play() is called
    computer = new Player(COMPUTER);
    human = new Player(HUMAN);
    marbleCount = rand.nextInt(91) + 10;
    turn = rand.nextInt(2);
    winner = HUMAN;
    // JOptionPane - Show number of marbles
    //JOptionPane.showInputDialog(marbleCount);

    play();
}

/**
 * The play method continues game play until the pile is reduced to 0.
 * Whoever takes the last marble loses the game. At the beginning of each
 * play, the number of marbles left is displayed. The player whose turn it
 * is calls the Player play method, sending it the number of marbles left.
 * When the player takes marbles, the marbleCount is decreased. When the
 * marbles are gone, the winner of the game is displayed.
 */
public void play()
// while there are marbles left
// if else for turn
// if its the computers turn you are going to call the computer's play
// method,
// last method in the player file
// call computer;s play method, send it marbleCount, and
// reduce marblecount by the amount the computer takes
// Then you need to check for a winner
// switch the turn
// else human's turn
// call the human's play method - send it marbleCount
// reduce marbleCount by the human's take
// check for a winner
// switch the turn
{
    while (marbleCount > 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There are " + marbleCount + "marbles left");
        int marblesTaken = 0;
        if (turn == 0) {
            marblesTaken = computer.play(marbleCount);
        } else {
            marblesTaken = human.play(marbleCount);
        }
        marbleCount = marbleCount - marblesTaken;
        turn = (marbleCount > 0 ? turn == 1 ? 0 : 1 : turn);
    }

    // At the end of play (when the loop exits), the winner is displayed
    if (turn == 0)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Computer wins!");
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Human wins!");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Nim();
}
```

}

And this is your player

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
  * Represents a player in the game of Nim. The player is either human or
  * computer. Humans are prompted for their plays.
  */
public class Player {
public static int   COMPUTER    = 0;

public static int   HUMAN       = 1;

private int         type;               // computer or human

/**
 * Constructs a player of type t. 0 is COMPUTER, 1 is HUMAN. If t is not 0
 * or 1, type will be set to HUMAN.
 * 
 * @param t
 *            type of player
 */
public Player(int t) {
    type = t;
    if (!(type == 0 || type == 1))
        type = 1;
}

/**
 * Determines how many marbles are taken, and returns that number. Human
 * player will be asked how many marbles they want to take. If the move is
 * illegal, they will be asked again until they select a legal move. The
 * computer will take a random number of marbles between 1 and pileSize/2.
 * 
 * @param pileSize
 *            the number of marbles in the pile
 * @return the number of marbles taken by the player
 */
public int play(int pileSize) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int numTaken;
    if (type == COMPUTER) {
        if (pileSize == 1) {
            numTaken = 1;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Computer took 1 marble ");
        } else {
            numTaken = r.nextInt(pileSize / 2) + 1; // POSSIBLE ERROR
            pileSize = pileSize - numTaken;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Computer took " + numTaken + "marbles ");
        }
    } else {
        boolean correct;
        do {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must take between " + pileSize/2 + " marbles");
            String numTakenbyhuman = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("There are " + pileSize + "marbles "
                    + "How many marbles will you take ?");
            numTaken = Integer.parseInt(numTakenbyhuman);
            // pileSize = pileSize - numTaken;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Human took " + numTaken + " marbles ");
            if (1 <= numTaken && numTaken < pileSize / 2)
                correct = false;
            else
                correct = true;

        } while (!correct);
        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must take between " +
        // pileSize + " 1 marbles");

    }
    return numTaken;

}
```

}

Hope this helps